# Variation of Weierstrass Approximation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous even function. Show that for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists an even polynomial $p(x)= \sum _{k=0} ^{n} a_k x^{2k}$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$ for any $x \in [-1,1]$. Show a similar result for a continuous odd function.

I know that since $f(x)$ is continuous, that a polynomial exists such that $|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$ by the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem. However, I do not know how to show that this polynomial is also even. The proof for the odd case should be basically the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial furnished by Weierstrass Approximation Theorem doesn't need to be even/odd in this case. But you can decompose $p$ in its even and odd parts $p=p_e+p_o$ where $p_e(x)=\frac{p(x)+p(-x)}{2}$ and $p_o(x)=\frac{p(x)-p(-x)}{2}$. Then $p_e$ will still be a good enough approximation to $f$ since $p_o$ will be small.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=f(\sqrt{|x|})$. $g$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$. There exists a polynomial $p$ such that $|g(x)-p(x)|\le\epsilon$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$. Now consider $q(x)=p(x^2)$.